# Error when creating ID for english.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stack-exchange, cookies

I get this error:

> English Language and Usage - Stack Exchange requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?

I'm sure that my Cookies are always enabled.

Is this happening to everyone, or is it just me?

Comment: What browser?  What version of that browser?

Comment: @rrchern Google chrome 6

Comment: same thing happening to me on electronics.stackexchange...using firefox 3.6.15 with Permit Cookies add-on but have allowed the domain.  works on all the other sites

Comment: @jacobsee: Just in case, this is solved for me.

Comment: thanks...just went over to electronics and i'm just logged in.  not sure what was happening before!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when logging into new Stack Exchange sites with a Google account that's already associated with existing Stack Exchange sites.

The solution is *not* to refresh the page giving the error. But to close the tab/window containing the error message then re-visit the new Stack Exchange site in a new tab/window. A JavaScript "Welcome Back" notification at the top of the screen should slide down after a few seconds.